# TextBox losing focus

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is baffling me. I have a Windows Form with a TextBox, 2 RadioButtons, an OK Button & a Cancel Button. I was mucking around with Tabbing, but I have now removed it, so TextBox1 is set to TabIndex=1 & TabStop=True, all the other fields are set to TabIndex=0 & TabStop=False.

To get to this Form,I execute the following code :

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChooseLeague.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ChooseLeague.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Me.Hide()
        MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.RadioButton1.Checked = False
        MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.RadioButton2.Checked = False
        MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.TextBox1.Text = ""
        MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.TextBox1.Focus()
        MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

The Form opens and the cursor is blinking in the TextBox as required. However, if I cancel from the Form & then go back into it via the same method, the cursor is NOT in the TextBox and the Cancel Button is highlighted / has Focus.

Why is this, any ideas ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are hiding and showing the form, it is showing the last focused control.  The focus call doesn't work until *after* the form is visible.

Try switching it around and use the `Select` method.

```
MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.Show()
MaintainDatabaseAddLeague.TextBox1.Select()
```

Comment: Is that the same with most controls ? I come from a Mainframe background and assumed that all settings should be in place before I Load the form !

Comment: Perfect, thank you LarsTech, and so simple, I have so much to learn !

Comment: @GaryHeath Pretty much.  Focus and Select are not settings though, they are methods.  Those particular methods only work on a visible form.